# Assign data to and call variable within a model

Tags: php, laravel

How do you assign data to and pull data from a variable in a laravel model?
The normal way I do it in PHP is

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public $foo = '';

    public static function baz( $bar )
    {
        $this->foo = $bar;
    }

    public static function greet()
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $this->foo;
    }

    public static function getGreeting( $bar )
    {
        self::baz( $bar );
        return self::greet();
    }
}
```

But this won't work and I get errors like

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Using $this when not in object context'
```

So, how in the hell do you add data to a variable and call it in a laravel model?

```
Controller

echo Foo::getGreeting( 'World' );
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call these functions? What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to edit database rows?

Comment: Static methods don't use ``$this->``, they use ``static::``, and you shouldn't really assign variables to them. I'm pretty sure this would work fine if you removed the ``static`` keywords and called the methods on an instantiated object.

Comment: I've updated the question to give a little more detail and an example of calling the model from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside static methods you can't refer to `$this` because there is no current object. You are working in a class context. So you can either rewrite your methods to use the `static` or `self` keyword (also change the variable to static) or do something like this (Laravel does this in several places in the `Model` class as well:

```
public static function getGreeting( $bar )
{
    $instance = new static;
    $instance->baz( $bar );
    return $instance->greet();
}
```

This essentially creates a new instance of the current class and then calls two methods non-statically. Don't forget to remove the `static` keyword on the other two methods.